# Python on windows removes created file

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a file with a python program. When I perform all the actions command line, they all work fine. The file is created.
When I perform the actions in a python script, the file does not exist after the script terminates.
I created a small script that demonstrates the behavior.

```
import os
import os.path

current_dir = os.getcwd()
output_file = os.path.join(current_dir, "locations.js")

print output_file

f = open(output_file, "w")
f.write("var locations = [")
f.write("{lat: 55.978467, lng: 9.863467}")
f.write("]")
f.close()

if os.path.isfile(output_file):
    print output_file + " exists"

exit()
```

Running the script from the command line, I get these results:

```
D:\Temp\GeoMap>python test.py
D:\Temp\GeoMap\locations.js
D:\Temp\GeoMap\locations.js exists

D:\Temp\GeoMap>dir locations.js
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is 0EBF-9720

 Directory of D:\Temp\GeoMap

File Not Found

D:\Temp\GeoMap>
```

Hence the file is actually created, but removed when the script terminates.

What do I need to do the keep the file?

Comment: Hi @Eric, I don't have your issue on Linux

Comment: I also tried your script on Windows 8.1, it can generate the file `locations.js`. Also I suggest using  parentheses when you want to print something

Comment: What do you get for `dir /a locations.js`?

Comment: I finally did nail this down to Comodo Internet Security. It runs my python script in a sandbox. I figured out how to add directories in Comodo which should be ignored for sandboxing. That finally solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by changing firewall settings.